# Easiest way to programmatically add files to a project

Tags: c#, automation

I want to programmatically add class files to a c# project.  Right now I'm thinking the fastest route may be to simply edit the xml file directly but I know there are api's for working with the project.

The thing is that I want to run an exe that just updates the file.  I don't want to have to have the target project open in Visual Studio which is what it seems like is necessary with the automation interfaces used by add-ins.

So does anyone know how to do this with an api or am I stuck with working directly with the xml?

Comment: Editing the XML sounds good. What are you trying to accomplish, though?

Comment: @minitech I wrote some code to generate classes based on my database schema and I'm just trying to simplify the process of updating the project they go in as much as possible when the schema changes.  Thing about editing xml is I see there are multiple ItemGroup nodes and I'm wondering if the 1st one is always references and the 2nd always project files or if I'm going to need to analyze the contents of them to find out which to add my files to.

Comment: it seems to me that you are inventing entity framework. it already has  template for normal EF entities, for EF context with POCO, for Self-Tracking entities, template for repository pattern and much more. If you are not into implementing features that EF doesn't have - ief bulk entity update, bulk insert, generic support for stor procs with multiple result sets etc, you better try to use that, as it has fine UI, allow update schema from DB and vise versa. Moreover 4.3 beta Code First manage db schema migrations quite good ( if you are not having couple of hundreds tables though ).

Comment: @vittore I looked into EF but it seemed more cumbersome at the time then I thought was necessary.  Admittedly I didn't give it much of a chance though after reading many reviews.  Rick Strahl (http://west-wind.com/weblog/) mentioned in an email to me that sometimes he almost even felt like ado.net had been more straightforward and maintainable.  From what I can tell of Jeff Atwood's blogs I think even StackOverflow uses plain linq2sql rather than EF.  There are multiple reasons I'm doing this, but one of the primary reasons is that I simply don't like interface of the EF.

Comment: @vittore Oh, another thing that always bothered me about l2s (though I do like it and use it for some stuff) is that in the Table<TEntity> class, the only contraint on TEntity is that it is a class.  Even though my code is nowhere near as complex as l2s, it's equivalent of a 'TEntity' class always inherits from a common base class so I can add common functionality that was more difficult to achieve in l2s.  Not sure if EF is similar to l2s in the regard or not but I imagine so.

Comment: that is good example where you will see power of EF, thanks to ability to use T4 for generating classes you can make you context, you classes inherit and implement whatever you want

Comment: also talking about simpler solution i like bltoolkit as lightweight DAL

Comment: and further to ADO.net is more straightforward, EF is logical ancestor of DataSets ( i wish it also has ability to do bulk inserts though ), and it depends on your project and architectural decisions made, if you like to use plain DataReaders and code everything on your own, or just generate strongly typed datasets and have ADO.NET do a lot of stuff for you , of course by price of performance, as you probably do not need tracking etc in all projects, however if you will really need all the features EF/DataSets gives you, i bet you won't come up with solution any simpler/faster than they does.

Comment: @vittore One difference w/ my code is it's not designed to query the db any way you can think of, but more to just get the data into the Business Objects where you can then use linq over them.  There's the ability to adjust the WHERE clause but beyond that you have to add specific functions to the data access layer to do anything more complex.  In that respect it actually is faster and simpler.  Tests show it's as literally as fast as doing identical queries straight from ssms, and though I may have to write specific data retrieval functions it will be simpler from the business logic layer.

Comment: @vittore I originally tried to do the same thing I'm doing now with l2s.  I don't want people to use l2s or EF in the other layers;  I want them working with actual business objects.  So in regard to the 'specific' functions I mentioned I would have done that anyway.

Comment: i do not fully understand what you describe, can you post some examples of the code ?

Comment: Well... I don't know if this is the ideal place to continue this conversation.  I would email you but I don't see one listed on your profile.  If you're interested though then maybe you could add one and we could talk more.  I would certainly value further input if you want to look at this in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is comprehensive support for T4 files which allow you programmatically generate files in the project, good example is Entity Framework templates for Self-Tracking entities and POCO, which you can get in the VS Gallery.
Also there are several good editors for T4 which allow you to have intellisence while editing templates

Comment: Yeah I looked into that a bit and am working towards implementing that route but the learning curve (though not huge) is more than I can handle and be able to get this thing done with what time I have over the next 2 or 3 days.  Basically I'm trying to get something to show my boss and get his approval before my team lead gets an opportunity to be part of this process.  He's one of those guys with a degree and very little experience who thinks he knows the best way to do everything.  The less input he has in design decisions the better.

Comment: Do you know where I could get some pre-made template samples?  I tried downloading a couple but I think they were maybe for an older version because they didn't work.

Comment: there are a lot of t4 templates, and those for EF i pointed you to, need you create entity framework model first and it will use t4 to generate classes based on xml.

Comment: check this 2 articles http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx , http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx. And yes, easiest example is here http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/how-to-create-a-simple-t4-template/

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried copy/pasting some examples from that last website but vs 2010 gave me errors.  Dunno if it's for a previous version or I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: Something to do with the directives not being formatted properly.  I ended up just editing the xml directly.